# nestjs Gateways emit an event to all connected sockets

Tags: nestjs

How to issue an event to all connected sockets?

```
    export class EventsGateway {

      @SubscribeMessage('message')

       async onEvent(client, data) {
        // The following is the use of `socket.io` to issue events to all connected sockets.
        // io.emit('message', data);
      }
    }
```

How do I perform this in nestjs?

Comment: This is a good question that many people may be searching if they can't quite find the appropriate documentation or don't understand the abstractions they're working with, not sure why it received any down votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NestJS allows you to create message listeners using decorators. Within this method, you are able to respond to the client by returning a [WsResponse](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways#multiple-responses) object.

However, NestJS also allows you to get the WebSocket instance using the [WebSocketServer](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways#server) decorator.

To send an Event to all connected clients you will need to use the `WebSocketServer` decorator and use the native WebSocket instance to emit a message, like so:

```ts
import WebSocketServer from '@nestjs/websockets'

export class EventsGateway {
  @WebSocketServer() server;

  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  onEvent(client: any, payload: any): Observable<WsResponse<any>> | any {
    this.server.emit('message', payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.